# Integrate $3^x$ using the $px + q$ rule

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm having trouble integrating $3^x$ using the $px + q$ rule. Can some please walk me through this?

Thanks

Comment: and the px + q rule is? Plus, $3^x$ is often considered  primitive as an integral

Comment: I suppose the $px+q$-rule is something like $p\int f(px+q)dx=\int f(px+q)d(px+q)$. I.e, a linear substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can simply take as primitive $$\int a^x \,\text{d}x = \dfrac{a^x}{\log a} + C$$

Suggestion: Verify for yourself that $$\frac{\text{d}}{dx}\left(\frac {a^x}{\log a} + C\right) = a^x$$

So $$\int 3^x \,\text{d}x = \dfrac{3^x}{\log 3} + C.$$

Answer (score 3):

And the $px+q$ rule is...?

You **can** use $3^x = e^{x\log 3}$ and the obvious change of variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct in what you think the $px+q$ rule is then take $f(x)=e^x$, $p=\log 3$, and $q=0$, with $\log$ the natural logarithm (of course!).

Comment: $\int f(px+q) p dx= F(px+q)+$ constant.

Comment: Perhaps worth an edit, adding to your Answer?

Comment: It probably should go into the question, but I don't have sufficient points to edit the question.